# SQL Retrieving varray elements of a subobject in Oracle 11g Database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am building a SQL query of a database where I am trying to retrieve an element of a `VARRAY` that is a subobject of several objects that is an element of another `VARRAY`.  I can successfully query subobjects of my first `VARRAY` like

```
SELECT o.data_obj.DATA_DQI.SOURCE_NUMBER SOURCE_NUMBER 
       from RTRD_W.rtrd_pri, table(NOMNL) o;
```

but the `SOURCE NUMBER` result is a varray and I can't seem to get the syntax right to access and element of it  I tried:

```
SELECT o.data_obj.DATA_DQI.SOURCE_NUMBER SOURCE_NUMBER.SRC_REF_VA(1) 
      from RTRD_W.rtrd_pri, table(NOMNL) o;
```

which I thought would retrieve the first element in the embedded varray, but it say there is an error in my SQL syntax.  Can anyone find the error in my syntax or show correct syntax for quering elements of a VARRAY that are subobjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the data from a VARRAY of VARRAYs by using an inline view and multiple cross-joins.

```
create or replace type v_test1 is varray(10) of number;
create or replace type v_test2 is varray(10) of v_test1;

create table test1
(
    a number,
    b v_test2
);

insert into test1 values(1, v_test2(v_test1(1, 2, 3), v_test1(4, 5, 6)));

select a, column_value b
from
(
    select a, column_value b
    from test1, table(b)
) data, table(data.b);

A   B
-   -
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   6
```

I excluded the objects in the middle to keep the example simple.  If you want more a more specific example it would help if you posted the DDL for all the relevant objects.

Comment: The example setup worked perfectly!  Thanks so much for helping me find the right way to structure my syntax